# Error while checking for multiple files based on a pattern in a directory in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm trying to check if there are some specific types of files in a directory and based on that I have few scripts that runs on them. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f Homology_Search/*tested.out ] && [ ! -f  Homology_Search/*mod.annotation.*sense.gff ]
    for i in Homology_Search/*tested.out; do python ../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation2.py $i $i.mod; done
    for i in Homology_Search/*tested.out.mod; do python ../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation3.py $i final_summary_table.tsv $i.sp.csv; done
    Rscript /final_summary_table_gen2.3.R
else if [ ! -f Homology_Search/*tested.out ]
    for i in Homology_Search/*tested.out; do python ../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation2.py $i $i.mod; done
    for i in Homology_Search/*tested.out.mod; do python ../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation3.py $i final_summary_table.tsv $i.sp.csv; done
    Rscript /final_summary_table_gen2.R
else if [ ! -f  Homology_Search/*mod.annotation.*sense.gff ]
    Rscript /final_summary_table_gen3.R
fi
```

For this particular case I have files that satisfy these first condition `Homology_Search/*tested.out` and `Homology_Search/*mod.annotation.*sense.gff` and so I expected to get an output file - `final_summary_table.mod.tsv` from `Rscript /final_summary_table_gen2.3.R` final command in that loop. However I am getting this error:

```
test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
test.sh: line 7: `else if [ -f ! Homology_Search/*tested.out ]'
```

I ran through the `shell-check` and i fixed few errors in my code and here is the updated code

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f "../Homology_Search/*tested.out" ] && [ ! -f "../Homology_Search/*mod.annotation.*sense.gff" ]; then
    for i in ../Homology_Search/*tested.out; do python ../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation2.py "$i" "$i".mod; done
    for i in ../Homology_Search/*tested.out.mod; do python ../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation3.py "$i" final_summary_table.tsv "$i".sp.csv; done
    Rscript final_summary_table_gen2.3.R
elif [ ! -f "../Homology_Search/*tested.out" ]; then
    for i in ../Homology_Search/*tested.out; do python../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation2.py "$i" "$i".mod; done
    for i in ../Homology_Search/*tested.out.mod; do python../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation3.py "$i" final_summary_table.tsv "$i".sp.csv; done
    Rscript final_summary_table_gen2.R
else
    Rscript final_summary_table_gen3.R
fi
```

It fixed most of the issues but there is still an issue in that the `else` loop is not working and it keeps giving an error when i try to have a directory that contains only `../Homology_Search/*mod.annotation.*sense.gff` files to test the `else` condition

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation2.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(infile, 'rU' ) as fh_in:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../Homology_Search/*tested.out'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're missing a few `then`s. Also, I think you meant `[ ! -f file ]` rather than the other way around.

Comment: Consider running it through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net)

Comment: The test command `[ ]` does not support file globbing with option `-f`. You have to check in another way if the files are present.

Comment: The test command `[ ]` is working fine, however the last condition is not working

Comment: It does not! Thats why your error occoures. Be warned: Your test command doesn't check for files named *like* `../Homology_Search/*tested.out`, but for a file *exactly* named `"../Homology_Search/*tested.out` (with * in filename!). Unless there is no file named exacly with asterisk, always your first then-path will be executed. As I said, no fileglobbing in test ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given, that your bash has the `compgen` builtin, you can use the following version of your script. As the test command `[ -f filename ]` does not support fileglobbing, you have to use something like compgen:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! compgen -G Homology_Search/*tested.out > /dev/null &&  ! compgen -G Homology_Search/*mod.annotation.*sense.gff > /dev/null
then 
    for i in Homology_Search/*tested.out; do python../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation2.py "$i" "$i.mod"; done
    for i in Homology_Search/*tested.out.mod; do python../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation3.py "$i" "final_summary_table.tsv" "$i.sp.csv"; done
    Rscript final_summary_table_gen2.3.R
elif  ! compgen -G Homology_Search/*tested.out > /dev/null
then
    for i in Homology_Search/*tested.out; do python../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation2.py "$i" "$i.mod"; done
    for i in Homology_Search/*tested.out.mod; do python../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation3.py "$i" "final_summary_table.tsv" "$i.sp.csv"; done
    Rscript final_summary_table_gen2.R
elif ! compgen -G  Homology_Search/*mod.annotation.*sense.gff > /dev/null
then
    Rscript final_summary_table_gen3.R
fi
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. `compgen` saved me from hell. I have modified my code a bit and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question if someone finds useful. Special thanks to @A.Grieco for the valuable hints

```
#!/bin/bash

if compgen -G "../Homology_Search/*tested.out" > /dev/null && compgen -G  "../Homology_Search/*mod.annotation.*sense.gff" > /dev/null
then
   for i in ../Homology_Search/*tested.out; do python ../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation2.py "$i" "$i".mod; done
   for i in ../Homology_Search/*tested.out.mod; do python ../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation3.py "$i" final_summary_table.tsv "$i".sp.csv; done
   Rscript final_summary_table_gen2.3.R

elif compgen -G "../Homology_Search/*tested.out" > /dev/null && ! compgen -G  "../Homology_Search/*mod.annotation.*sense.gff" > /dev/null
then
   for i in ../Homology_Search/*tested.out; do python ../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation2.py "$i" "$i".mod; done
   for i in ../Homology_Search/*tested.out.mod; do python ../../filter_lincRNA_sequences_annotation3.py "$i" final_summary_table.tsv "$i".sp.csv; done
   Rscript final_summary_table_gen2.R

elif ! compgen -G "../Homology_Search/*tested.out" > /dev/null && compgen -G  "../Homology_Search/*mod.annotation.*sense.gff" > /dev/null
then
    Rscript final_summary_table_gen3.R

fi
```